# Please comment on my Spring-Rabbit AQMP logger class

Tags: spring-amqp

I am writing a SpringBoot 4 app and want to send log messages from my controllers using RabbitMQ 3.5.5. Originally I wrote a class, using the Java API, to encapsulate the Rabbit stuff, but I was advised that each client request will be handled in a different thread. I was also told that if I allocate a channel each time I send that the performance will be poor, so I should use the Spring RabbitMQ implementation which handles this issue for me.

I rewrote my class, and I'm hoping someone is willing to look at it. Although it seems to work nicely, I'm still new to SpringBoot, so I feel that I don't have a complete understanding of how the magic is implemented. My primary concerns for this class are (1) thread safety and (2) performance.

Currently, I'm autowiring this class in my controllers like this:

```
@Autowired
private RabbitLogger rl;
```

I think this gives me a new instance of RabbitLogger and if so I think I'm good on thread safety, but I'm not sure. The new RabbitLogger class uses the Spring RabbitMQ client implementation.

I'll post my class and an excerpt from a controller below. In the logger class, I use spring.rabbitmq application.properties for the username, password and host, and I created my own properties for the queue name and exchange name.

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated. This is a highly visible project at my organization and I really need it to be as close to perfect as possible. Thank you.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitLogger 
{
    @Value("${rabbit.queue:uadec_queue}")
    private String queueName;

    @Value("${rabbit.exchange:uadec_exchange}")
    private String exchangeName;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String rabbitUn;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String rabbitPw;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
    private String rabbitHost;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    private void dumpConfig()
    {
        Logger.getGlobal().config(() -> "RabbitMQ Hostname: " + rabbitHost);
        Logger.getGlobal().config(() -> "RabbitMQ Exchange Name: " + exchangeName);
        Logger.getGlobal().config(() -> "RabbitMQ Queue Name: " + queueName);
        Logger.getGlobal().config(() -> "RabbitMQ Username: " + rabbitUn);
        Logger.getGlobal().config(() -> "RabbitMQ Password: " + rabbitPw);
    }

    public void logLoginUserNameNotFound(String IP, String s)
    {
        String message = IP + "\tLOGIN_USER_NOT_FOUND\t" + s;
        send(message);
    }

    public void logLoginBadPassword(String IP, String s)
    {
        String message = IP + "\tLOGIN_BAD_PASSWORD\t" + s;

        send(message);
    }


    public void logLoginSuccess(String IP, String s)
    {
        String message = IP + "\tLOGIN_SUCCESS\t" + s;

        send(message);
    }

    public void logDecisionRendered(String IP, String userId, String decision)
    {
        String message = IP + "\tDECISION_RENDERED\t" + userId + "\t" + decision;

        send(message);
    }

    private void send(String s)
    {
        if(rabbitTemplate == null)
        {
            Logger.getGlobal().fine(() -> "Unable to send Rabbit Message - rabbitTemplate is null");
            return;
        }

        if(queueName == null)
        {
            Logger.getGlobal().fine(() -> "Unable to send Rabbit Message - queueName is null");
            return;
        }

        String time = ZonedDateTime.now().toString();
        String message = time + "\t" + s + "\r\n";

        try
        {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);

            Logger.getGlobal().finest(() -> "Sent Rabbit Message: " + message);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.getGlobal().finest(() -> "Failed sending Rabbit Message: " + message);
            Logger.getGlobal().finest(() -> "Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller starts like this:

```
@Controller
public class Login_FormController 
{
    private String decisionText = null;

    @Autowired
    private AdminDataRepository adRep;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicantCredentialsDataRepository acRep;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitLogger rl;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginSumbit(@Valid 
        @ModelAttribute("loginForm") ApplicantCredentialsData applicantCredentialsData,
        BindingResult br,
        Model model,
        HttpServletRequest serReq)
    {

        Blah Blah Blah

        // Log something
        rl.logLoginSuccess(remoteIp, userId);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how we can help you and I really will be glad to see other vision for your question, but from my perspective everything looks good.

Yes, there are a lot of code specific to your project, but you use Spring AMQP correctly.

The `RabbitTemplate` is really thread-safe, so no need to worry about concurrent `convertAndSend` invocation.

The code

```
@Autowired
private RabbitLogger rl;
```

in your `Login_FormController` (BTW it's bad class name from Java convernsion perspective) says that it will use only one instance from the container - `singleton`. And that is just because your `RabbitLogger` is defined without any `scope`. I'd say don't worry about this subject, if you don't understand Spring properly. Just read documentation on the matter for now!

The Spring Boot *magic* is around population to the application context (your one!) some built-in beans, like `RabbitTemplate` based on the common options from the `application.properties`. You can find how it is done from the `RabbitAutoConfiguration`.

What else to say you?..

We have an [`AmqpAppender`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/tree/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/log4j) for `log4j` and for `logback` as out-of-the-box components to allow to follow with standard logging system config and API, but send logs to the AMQP.

Comment: Thanks Artem, you helped me greatly be confirming that my code is thread safe. I am concerned about your comment that my form controller is a singleton. This app has to handle about 30,000 requests in just a few minutes. Did I create a bottleneck?

Comment: No, everything is good. I don't see any bottlenecks. And from other side for the good performance and throughput it's really better to have everything as singleton and make your application as stateless. It's a big story to describe, but believe me: if you follow with the Spring recommendations, you won't fall in the final solution!

Comment: Okay thanks again, I'll read up on Bean scoping. How does rabbitTemplate arbitrate threads? Does it protect the send call? Does it have a pool of channels? I'm confused about how, if there is one instance that the threads share, its not a bottleneck.

Comment: M-m-m. From big height yes, it is based on the `pool of channels`, but by default it is only `1` in the `CachingConnectionFactory`. So, yes, any other concurrent call initiates the new `channel` and close it in the end of `send()` operation. You can override that in your `RabbitLogger` within `@PostConstruct` using `setChannelCacheSize()`

Comment: Excellent, I'll check that out. You have been very generous with your time, thank you very much!